# SQLSRV PHP removing selected record

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, delete-record

There are not many tutorials in the web about Mssql using sqlsrv driver, so I followed similar tutorials with MySQL and using sqlsrv API I was converting my code. So far all works, I can add records with popup form etc.

Now I'm trying to delete multiple records with checkbox. I tried all the tutorials I was able to find but it still does not work.

There is no effect after selecting checkbox and pressing delete apart question from onDelete script which asking me if I like to delete records.

I have two php files - **SQLTest.php** and **delete.php**.

**Code from SQLTest.php**

```
<h1>SQL Testing</h1>
<h1>Component Group Modifications</h1>

<table class="table_general">
<tbody>

<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th colspan="2">MODIFICATIONS</th>
  <th colspan="3">APPLICABLE WORKSHEET</th> 
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>

<?php
$serverName = "THOMAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) 
{
     echo "Connected to Database !";
}
else
{
     echo "Opps - something went wrong !";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.modIndex";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
if ($query === false){  exit("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{  
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["recordID"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["first"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["second"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["third"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["fourth"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["fifth"];?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" value="<?php echo $row["recordID"];?>"></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
?>

</tbody>
<input type="button" value="Delete Selected Records" action="delete.php" method="post" onclick="return onDelete();"/>
</table>

</section>
</section>
```

Code from delete.php

```
<?php

$serverName = "THOMAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "<script>alert('Opps - something went wrong !');</script>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["chkDel"]);$i++)
{
    if($_POST["chkDel"][$i] != "")

        {
            $tsql = "DELETE FROM dbo.modIndex ";
            $tsql = "WHERE recordID = '".$_POST["chkDel"][$i]."'  "; 
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
        }
}
    echo "Record Deleted.";

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $tsql);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

Short onDelate function:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function onDelete()
    {
        if(confirm('Do you want to delete ?')==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my SQL details:

database -> test -> table : dbo.modIndex
recordID - first - second - third - fourth - fifth

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And you should not be echoing "record deleted" until you've CONFIRMED that something actually happened. you're simply assuming your delete query succeeded, which is exactly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for the advice. Yes I will revise this code but I really have to solved my problem with deleting the records first. Thank you.

Comment: regarding delete.php: a) have you checked that the data "looks" as you expect? e.g. via var_export($_POST) b) have you checked that the for-loop/if-statement is entered at least once? e.g. print the query before sending it to the sqlserver. c) there's no error handling for the return value of sqlsrv_query(), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @VolkerK thank you for advice. I believe I understand correctly and added error handling to my code and now is showing me an error as below in my recent post.

Comment: VolkerK - I did checked with var_export($_POST) the variables but I`m not sure what to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_POST["chkDel"]) || !is_array($_POST["chkDel"]) ) {
    die('missing or wrong parameter "chkDel"');
}

$serverName = "THOMAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    echo "<script>alert('Opps - something went wrong !');</script>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$query = 'DELETE FROM dbo.modIndex WHERE ID=?';
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array(&$id));
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

foreach( $_POST["chkDel"] as $id ) {
    if( !sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
}
```

Comment: VolkerK - you are the Man ! Thank you for your help. I new that I had to use prepare and exec but I had problems to put it together. Thank you again all works great !

Answer (score 0):

I change the code as VolkerK suggested using POST method and added error handling to delete.php which is giving me more info.

Changes below:

```
    <form name="frmMain" action="delete.php" method="post" OnSubmit="return onDelete();">

<table class="table_general">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th>CustomerID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>CountryCode</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>Used</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>

<?php
$serverName = "THOMAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"", "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) 

{
     echo "Connected to Database !";
}
else
{
     echo "Opps - something went wrong !";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.customer";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
if ($query === false){  exit("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
while ($objResult = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))

{  

?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$objResult["CustomerID"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["Name"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["Email"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["CountryCode"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["Budget"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["Used"];?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" value="<?=$objResult["CustomerID"];?>"></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);

?>
</tbody>

<input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete">
</table>
</form>
```

And delete.php give me now error after selecting one checkbox and pressing delete button:

delete.php code:

```
    <?php

$serverName = "THOMAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "<script>alert('Opps - something went wrong !');</script>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["chkDel"]);$i++)
{
    if($_POST["chkDel"][$i] != "")

        {
            $tsql = "DELETE FROM dbo.customer";
            $strSQL .="WHERE CustomerID = '".$_POST["chkDel"][$i]."' ";
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $strSQL);
            var_export($_POST);

        }

        print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
        }


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $tsql);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

And error given after checking on checkbox from three available.

```
       Array
(
    [chkDel] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [btnDelete] => Delete
)
chkDel=Array<br />btnDelete=Delete<br />

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -14
            [code] => -14
            [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
            [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
        )

)
```

My database details:

database -> test -> table : dbo.customer -> CustomerID - Name - Email - CountryCode - Budget - Used.

I`m new to SQL PHP and this is more difficult considering there is not many tutorials in the web regarding mssql and php.

Thank you all of you for help and advice.

Comment: You can't pass the WHERE clause as parameter(s) to sqlsrv_query(). Take a look at the examples at http://docs.php.net/sqlsrv_query

Comment: I spend a lot of time trying to build the edit form in order to edit selected by checbox row of records. Is there any chance to convert delete.php to allow edit the selected row of records. I mentioned delete.php as I believe it will be simillar approach when editing. I tried to accomplished this but I`m getting problems to display selected record for editing in separated form. In this case I will reuse my insert.php form.

Any help ?

Thank you,